# Missing branch from 'git branch -a' but shows up with 'git ls-remote origin'

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-branch, git-checkout

I created a branch through the Azure DevOps portal, and I want to checkout the branch. However, when I run

`git checkout remotes/origin/dev/<branch name>`

It returns "error: pathspec 'remotes/origin/dev/branchname' did not match any file(s) known to git"

So I run

`git branch -a`

And the branch is not in the output.

So then I run

`git ls-remote origin`

and the branch is there and has the same refs/heads/ prefix as the branches that show up with 'git branch -a'! Is there a different way I can fetch the branches that show up from 'git ls-remote origin'?

Comment: Did you try: `git checkout <branch name>`? Let Git worry about it ;)

Comment: Tried `git fetch` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to `fetch` the changes from the remote first to make sure the heads, commits and tags from the remote are available in your local repo. Afterwards you can switch to the branch using `checkout`.